# Doxygen integration with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, integration, doxygen

Most of the problems discussed here when doxygen and VS2010 are mentioned are focusing generation comments in the source code. We have built some macros to get these automatically. My question is targeting in another direction:

I've seen that when you press the F1-Key when the cursor is on a DirectX method, Visual Studio 2010 will automatically open the online help. Does anyone know a way to include a local doxygen into this help?

Thanks in advance
Elmo

Comment: F1 is context-sensitive help.  It doesn't just apply to DirectX methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you are looking for but generally you can create the help and then try to convert it. See [Additional CHM for VisualStudio F1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274032/additional-chm-for-visualstudio-f1) for example (it is not the chm itself but you can try to take a look at these tools to find a way).
An alternative way of doing it might be using something like this http://doxygenbrowseraddin.codeplex.com/