# Additional CHM for VisualStudio F1?

Tags: visual-studio, chm

Is there a way to include additional help files (.chm) in VisualStudio (2010), so that when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> (on a function), it automatically opens the new help file on the correct site?
Thank you.

Comment: VS2010 uses something else instead of .chm files.

Comment: htmlhelp2 to be exact. VS2012 uses htmlhelp3. CHM is htmlhelp1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible in VS 2010. It was possible in VS 2002-2008 only (our product [VSdocman](http://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/overview.html) can do it). To explain:

1. The **Html Help 1** format (CHM) was used in VS 6 and earlier.
2. VS 2002, 2003, 2005 and 2008 used the **MS Help 2** format (HxS). But it was possible to use also CHM for additional custom F1 help.
3. VS 2010 uses the **MS Help Viewer 1** format (MSHC) and VS 2012 uses the **MS Help Viewer 2** format (MSHC). There are only minor differences between them and you can consider them to be the same (some call this format as MS Help3). There is no way to include an additional help in a format other than MSHC.

So if you want to add your own <kbd>F1</kbd> help, you need to create an MSHC file. It's not that difficult. It's only a list of specially formatted HTML files, zipped into single MSHC file. There are tools that help you with that. For example our VSdocman or free mshcMigrate.exe which can convert your existing CHM to MSHC.

Answer (score 0):

Some more info on [mshcMigrate](http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/home)

Copied from their site:

> Inputs
>
> Migrates both HTML Help & MS Help 2 to Help Viewer format. Converts projects files (.hxc, .hhp) & compiled help files (.hxs, .chm), as well as help source folders.
>
> Outputs
>
> Outputs include .mshc & .cab help package files as well as the .msha manifest file.
>
> Other Features
>
> The application includes several additional tools that allows you to test, install/uninstall, view the HelpLibManager output log, perform API calls, and explore the help library data store. The utility can also be operated in batch mode for overnight builds and command line operation